# How can I speed up this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have to optimize this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  sfo.entity_id,
  sfo.created_at,
  sfoa.postcode,
  sfo.customer_id
FROM sales_flat_order sfo
  JOIN sales_flat_order_address sfoa
    ON sfo.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id
WHERE sfo.entity_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT
  order_id
FROM sales_flat_order_item
WHERE sku = 'whatever'
OR sku = 'whatever1')
```

This runs a while and I guess its because of the subselect. I know using a join here might speed it up, but I failed to make it work so far. Any ideas on how to speed that up?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the plan say?

Comment: I don't think it will change anything, but the `distinct` in the sub-select is useless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Why do you think it wouldnt change the speed?

Comment: But it's a simple join (or at least it should be). I don't understand how you can construct a perfectly good join in one line and then fail to do the same thing on the next line !?!?

Comment: @user4095519: because the optimizer should already remove it

Comment: Please post your schema as `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, so we can see where you have indexes. Also, it would be interesting how many entries each table has.

Answer (score 2):

I would just do it as an extra level of join.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      sfo.entity_id,
      sfo.created_at,
      sfoa.postcode,
      sfo.customer_id
FROM sales_flat_order sfo
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_address sfoa
ON sfo.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item sfoi
ON sfo.entity_id = sfoi.order_id
WHERE sku IN ('whatever', 'whatever1')
```

Assuming that you have an index on the sku field of the sales_flat_order_item  table, an index on the entity_id on the sales_flat_order table and an index on the parent_id on the sales_flat_order_address table then this should be pretty quick.

Without indexes then pretty much any query will run very slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Would adding `INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item ON sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id` and then using `GROUP BY sfo.entity_id` do the trick?

I'm assuming the table of sales order items has links to the orders those items belong to in order_id. You can then add the sku requirements to the outer query and get rid of the subquery. Providing you have proper indicing this might speed up your query.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it doesnt speed up the query, in fact, it slows it down :D. From 7.5 secs with the sub to 11 with the join.

Comment: Try using EXPLAIN (in front of the query) to see if it's doing any slow 'TABLE SCAN' or similar operations. If it does, you may need to get the database admin to create appropriate indices and foreign keys.